# How to represent any "duration" or "period" in Joda time?

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to represent 24 hours as a "duration". That is it should be from **ONLY from 00:00:00 to 24:00:00**. Things like 12AM today to 12AM tomorrow are NOT ok. It is also 24 hours but, its not what I want. Also, there should be no concept of date or day attached to this "duration".

How do I do this using Joda Time ?

**EDIT -**

Use case - 
'
I want to create a scheduling program. The 24 hour "period" is split into slices of any size such as 20min, 30 min or 1 hour. I only want to use Joda to create a 24hr time "period" and slices of that time period". I know that joda cannot do any shceduling.

Eg.

Slices of 1 hr -

```
00:00:00 - 01:00:00
01:00:00 - 02:00:00
all the way up to -
23:00:00 - 24:00:00
```

Schedule -

```
00:00:00 - 07:00:00 - sleep
07:00:00 - 08:00:00 - get ready for work
08:00:00 - 09:00:00 - drive to work
09:00:00 - 17:00:00 - work
etc...
```

This is the schedule for weekdays. Weekends are for relaxing. :)

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve. You can easily create a `Duration` of 24 hours, but that's *not* necessarily the same as "the length of time from midnight to midnight". How do you want to *use* this value once you've got it?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Sorry. I added the details to the question. If its ok, then please up vote me.

Comment: It's still not obvious what operations you expect to be valid on such an object. I strongly suspect that Joda Time doesn't provide anything which does it all for you - you'll need to create your own type, but that'll be reasonable easy.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I only want to use Joda to create a 24hr time "period" and slices of that time period". I don't expect joda to do any scheduling for me because I know that joda cannot do any scheduling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this tempting [`Period` class](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html)... Just don't set date fields on it, only time fields.

Or there's [`LocalTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html), which represents a time of day.

---

Based on your edit, it sounds like a combination of `LocalTime` plus a number indicating how long the slot is (in minutes or whatever units make sense to you). So you might have a `ScheduleEntry` class which has `LocalTime` member for when the schedule entry starts, and an `int` for how long it lasts.

Comment: T.J crowder - Thanks. I added some more information to my question. Will that change your answer ?

Comment: I suspect `LocalTime` will be part of the solution, yes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I am not able to figure out what you said. Please tell me a little more. My main aim is to be able to create time slices out of a day of 24hr. The assignment of tasks and scheduling becomes easy to do after that.

Comment: @JediKnight: What don't you understand? Creating a class with members?